# Java Servlet: Pick files to download

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm pretty new to Java Servlets/Apache Tomcat/etc but I was able to find some handy resources on how I can implement Download and Upload functionality.

When the user wants to upload a file, they click the button, and they are prompted to select a file. However, when they want to download a file, they only have the choice of just the one file (specified in the servlet).

So, my question is: Is there a way to list out the directory somehow that would let the user pick a particular file, and then download that file?

Below is my code if you need a point of reference:

NOTE: This code works, I just want to know how I can expand on it with the desired effect I want.

```
package testPackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/DownloadServlet")
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final String absFilePath = "/test/files/download/test.txt";
    private static final String relFilePath = "/files/download/test.txt";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {   
        //Quick switch to determine what type of path to user
        boolean useAbsolute = false;    //Defaults to relative

        //Initialize a new File
        File downloadFile = new File("");

        //Check if we want to use the absolute file path
        if(useAbsolute)
        {
            //Read the input file from the absolute path
            downloadFile = new File(absFilePath);
        }

        //Otherwise, we are using relative
        else
        {
            //Read the input file from the relative path
            String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relFilePath);
            downloadFile = new File(relativePath);
            //System.out.println("Relative Path: " + relativePath);         
        }

        //Open up the FileInputStream
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

        //Obtain the Servlet Context
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        //Get the MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(absFilePath);

        //If we don't get a type, default to binary
        if(mimeType == null)
        {
            //Set to binary type if the MIME mapping is not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        //Just some logging
        System.out.println("MIME Type: " + mimeType);

        //Modify Servlet Response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

        //Set the header key/value
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        //Obtain the response output stream
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        //While there are bytes to write
        while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        //Close the streams
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Just list files in selected directory and generate downloaded link to each file. It is easy, you must just take care that link for directory must end with slash.

Comment: @Leos No you don't. Tomcat will work it out.

Comment: @EJP, I don't think Tomcat takes care of it, but rather the OS. Which means on some OSs Leos might be right.

Comment: It is not about tomcat or os, but browser. If you use relative links and directories do not trail with slash then link will replace last part of path instead of appending behind it. I have written such servlet twice.

Comment: I can recommend following implementation, it is working fine: http://balusc.blogspot.cz/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html